# How to write ajax in a function and return its value

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to write ajax inside a function and return its value and depending on value do something

```
check_email_present = (email) ->
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/donor/check_email_present",
    data: { email: email },
    success:(data) ->
      return data
    error:(data) ->
      return false
  })
```

I call this function like

```
  return_value = check_email_present(email)
  console.log(return_value)
```

I can see the object in log, when it try to print return_value.responseText i get undefined.

I also tried console.log(JSON.parse(return_value))

Within success function i'm able to do it(check data with if condition), but i want to return data back to a variable and then check it

Comment: What should be the content of data in success ? Give an example ?

Comment: If the response is a JSON data you can add dataType parameter in the Ajax request as `dataType:json",`

Comment: I'm returning a normal string value @SherinJose

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to `return` stuff from asynchronous functions. Rather use a callback:

```
check_email_present = (email, done) ->
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/donor/check_email_present",
    data: { email: email },
    success:(data) ->
      done(data)
    error:(data) ->
      done(null)
  })
```

and then:

```
check_email_present(email, return_value -> console.log(return_value))
```